# Submitting from a dynamically generated form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have made a dynamically generated a form which creates some selects and input boxes.

I need to do a form submit and need all the data from the selects and inputs into individual variables.

The code goes like this:

HTML CODE :

```
<body>
<div id="main1">
    <input type="button" onclick="addSelectBox ()" name="clickme" value="+" />
    <input type="button" onclick="removeSelect();" value="-" />
    <input type="button" onclick="xmlData();" value="XML" />
</div>
<form id="autoPopulation_form">
    <div id="main"></div>
</form>
```

JS CODE:

```
var selele = 0;
var brindex = 0;

function addSelectBox() {

    selele = selele + 1;
    var spantag = document.createElement("span");
    spantag.setAttribute("id", selele);

    var parentDiv = document.getElementById("main");
    var selectElement = document.createElement("select");
    var selectElement1 = document.createElement("select");
    var selectElement2 = document.createElement("select");
    var selectElement3 = document.createElement("select");
    var textbox = document.createElement('input');
    textbox.setAttribute("name", "text" + selele);

    var arr = new Array("Stocks", "MutualFunds");
    var arr2 = new Array("individual", "401k", "IRA");
    var arr3 = new Array("contains", "equals");
    var arr4 = new Array("scrapedaccounttype", "scrapedtransactiontype");

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var option = new Option(arr[i]);
        selectElement.options[selectElement.options.length] = option;
        selectElement.setAttribute("name", "tag" + selele);
    }


    for (var i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
        var option = new Option(arr2[i]);
        selectElement1.options[selectElement1.options.length] = option;
        selectElement1.setAttribute("name", "acctType" + selele);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < arr3.length; i++) {
        var option = new Option(arr3[i]);
        selectElement2.options[selectElement2.options.length] = option;
        selectElement2.setAttribute("name", "compare" + selele);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < arr4.length; i++) {
        var option = new Option(arr4[i]);
        selectElement3.options[selectElement3.options.length] = option;
        selectElement3.setAttribute("name", "match_name" + selele);
    }



    spantag.appendChild(selectElement);
    spantag.appendChild(selectElement1);
    spantag.appendChild(selectElement2);
    spantag.appendChild(selectElement3);
    spantag.appendChild(textbox);


    parentDiv.appendChild(spantag);
    linebreak();

};

function removeSelect() {
    var parentDiv = document.getElementById("main");
    var removetg = document.getElementById(selele);
    if (selele != 1) {
        parentDiv.removeChild(removetg);
        selele = selele - 1;


    } else {
        parentDiv.removeChild(removetg);
        parentDiv.innerHTML = "";
        selele = selele - 1;
    }
    removeBreak();
};

function linebreak() {

    brindex = brindex + 1;
    var brtag = document.createElement("br");
    brtag.setAttribute("id", brindex);
    var parentDiv = document.getElementById("main");
    parentDiv.appendChild(brtag);
};

function linespace() {

    var myElement = document.createElement("span");
    myElement.innerHTML = "&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp";
    var parentDiv = document.getElementById("main");
    parentDiv.appendChild(myElement);
};

function removeBreak() {
    var myElement = document.getElementById(brindex);
    var parentDiv = document.getElementById("main");
    brindex = brindex - 1;
    parentDiv.removeChild(myElement);
};

function xmlData() {


    xmlDoc = loadXMLDoc("data.xml");

    newel = xmlDoc.createElement("edition");

    x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("span")[0];
    x.appendChild(newel);

};
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3542N/2/) FOR THE SAME :

What I basically want to do is I need all the textboxes with name "text1","text2","text3 in different var's (variables).

I have heard about the jQuery [.serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/), but would it help my cause and it would be good if anybody can show me the same in my Fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

use `FormData()` method to serialize your form:

```
document.getElementByid('autoPopulation_form').onSubmit = function(){
    var frmData = new FormData(this);
    console.log(frmData);
};
```

output of it *(tested with clicked + one time)*:

```
?tag1=Stocks&acctType1=individual&compare1=contains
 &match_name1=scrapedaccounttype
 &text1=gsdfgsdgfsgsdfgsdf"
```

---

Note: ***You have to have a submit button to submit the form.***

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3542N/3/)

#### [Fiddle with method post](http://jsfiddle.net/3542N/4/)

Comment: how did you check the output, `{"error": "Please use POST request"}` when I change the form method="post" , then it throws a pretty long error. 

I guess jsfiddle doesn't allow console.log

Comment: You should not use this in jsfiddle, it was just a demo to show you how FormData will serialize your form's data.

Comment: And if you want to see your data with `method="post"` then do submit your form and go to the network tab in the chrome inspector and click the last request named `_display/` then you will get a popup at the right side there you have to find **Form Data** which is below request headers.

Comment: I still really can't figure out how to use this formdata

Comment: @rahul888 would you be more specific about your requirement then i would try to answer it properly in accordance of your requirement.

Comment: Hi Jai : I need the all the inputs of the form in separate variable's so that I can use all the variable's individually in some other function to do some more modifications

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49526/discussion-between-rahul888-and-jai)